# Custom protocol delegate method not calling

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, swift-protocols

I am trying to change lable of one view controller from another view controller using custom protocol but its delegate method is not being called

ViewController3 code:

when i click on close button it's delegate method is not being called in my ViewController2.

```
protocol ViewController3Delegate: class {

  func changeLable(_ text: String)
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

  weak var delegate: ViewController3Delegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }

  @IBAction func btnCloseAction(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.changeLable("fillter applied")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

ViewController2 code:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController,ViewController3Delegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var lblReport: UILabel!

  let VC3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    VC3.delegate = self
  }

  func changeLable(_ text: String) {

    print("delegate called")
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }
}
```

**Anybody knows where i am wrong, please suggest me some solution**

Comment: As you do not add `VC3.view` as subview, I suspect you have two `ViewController3` instances. On as your property in `ViewController2` (which you do not see) and one which we do not see the code for. Maybe instantiated by Storyboard. `ViewController2`s `btnCloseAction` is called, but its `delegate`is not set.

Comment: @shallowThought what is the solution i had tried many alternatives but it is not working.

Comment: Did you understand my suspect?

Comment: nope.i am not getting
i am having tabbar controller with 3 controller, when i click on second tab a view appears and close button action  current view controller gets dissmissed and want to change lable of visible view controller.for all 3 controller i am using xib

Comment: You are creating a `ViewController3` here: `let VC3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)`. But you never use it. Thus you can not see it. As you can not see it, you can not press a button on it. Delete the complete line to find out that it does not change the behaviour of your app in any way. Your posted code does not show the `ViewController3` that you actually see, so we can not help with that without more information.

Comment: what information do you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148215/discussion-between-shallowthought-and-chetan-panchal).

Comment: @chetanpanchal See my answer

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined a delegate in your ViewController2 which will be used to the delegate in ViewController3 .

See This :

```
 protocol ViewController3Delegate: class {

      func changeLable(_ text: String)
    }

    class ViewController3: UIViewController {

      weak var delegate: ViewController3Delegate?

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

      }

      @IBAction func btnCloseAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if delgate !=nil {

        delegate?.changeLable("fillter applied")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
      }
    }
```

And then in your ViewController2 class :

```
    class ViewController2: UIViewController,ViewController3Delegate {

      @IBOutlet weak var lblReport: UILabel!


      override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
      }

      func changeLable(_ text: String) {

        print("delegate called")
      }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

      }
          override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
             {

                 if segue.identifier = "Yoursegueientifier"
                  {
                     let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController3
                     vc.delegate = self
                  }                
            }
    }
```

**Note** : You have to define your segueidentifer name in your storyboard

Comment: thanks for suggestion but with my case its different i am having tabbar controller with 3 tabs so its not working, if you know how to work with delegate with tabbar please do suggest me some solution

Comment: so you want to pass data between tabs ?

Comment: yes, its like applying filter, i am having tabbar controller with 3 tabs, first and third tab contain data on which filter can be applied from tab 2 on clicking tab 2 a view is presented to show filters options based on filter data should get filtered it can be first view or third view it does not matter, i have tried working with delegate on tabbar controller it is working i dont know the reason why it is not working with other controller

Answer (score 0):

You should first present ViewController3 from ViewController2 like this:

```
let VC3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)
VC3.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(VC3, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also, you can delete this line above viewDidLoad

```
let VC3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)
```